# Delete Selected Text in Richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a `richtextbox` and i want to `delete` not `cut` the selected when the user presses a button.

I have used

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SendKeys.Send("DELETE");
}
```

This works but i want to know another way to do it.

I have tried

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectedText.Replace(richTextBox1.SelectedText, "");
}
```

This doesn't perform any action.

Pls what can i do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
   richTextBox1.SelectedText = "";
}
```

Your code doesn't work because the string is `immutable`, you can't change the `richTextBox1.SelectedText` that way. All the methods (`Replace`, `Insert`, ...) performed on a `string` will create a new `string`. This new string will be used to initialize your string variable if you need.

Comment: Note that this won't work if `ReadOnly` is set to `true`.

Comment: Selection.Text="" is what I required.

Comment: This just highlights the selected text, it doesn't delete it

Comment: In .NET 5 this works even with `ReadOnly` set to `true`

Answer (score 1):

The following line of code works for me:

```
SendKeys.Send("{DELETE}");
```

Click [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) to visit the Official documentation on SendKeys methods.